# SubSonic - Generate SQL uses nvarchar instead of varchar which causes Index Scan instead of Seek

Tags: subsonic, parameterized

I am using the SubSonic SimpleRepository template for my application.  I have created an ASP .NET WebForms project in VS2010 pointing to a SQL 2000 database.

I am having an issue where SubSonic is always using nvarchar in the parameterized queries instead of varchar.  This causes SQL to do an Index Scan instead of an Index Seek.  I have taken the SQL from the Profiler and altered it to make the parameters varchar like the table's fields and it executes very quickly (<1 second versus 8 seconds).

**SubSonic Query from Profiler**

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT [t0].[ADDRESS_L1], [t0].[ADDRESS_L2], [t0].[ADDRESS_L3], [t0].[CITY], [t0].[COUNTRY] FROM [aveadmin].[SAPADD] AS t0 WHERE (([t0].[SITE_ID] = @p0) AND ((([t0].[ADDRESS_TYPE] = @p1) AND 1 <> 0) OR (([t0].[ADDRESS_TYPE] = @p2) AND 0 <> 0)))', N'@p0 nvarchar(16),@p1 nvarchar(2),@p2 nvarchar(2)', @p0 = N'BCF8A0A27E543EE1', @p1 = N'00', @p2 = N'03'
```

**Manually Modified Query**

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT [t0].[ADDRESS_L1], [t0].[ADDRESS_L2], [t0].[ADDRESS_L3], [t0].[CITY], [t0].[COUNTRY] FROM [aveadmin].[SAPADD] AS t0 WHERE (([t0].[SITE_ID] = @p0) AND ((([t0].[ADDRESS_TYPE] = @p1) AND 1 <> 0) OR (([t0].[ADDRESS_TYPE] = @p2) AND 0 <> 0)))', N'@p0 varchar(16),@p1 varchar(2),@p2 varchar(2)', @p0 = N'BCF8A0A27E543EE1', @p1 = N'00', @p2 = N'03'
```

The `SITE_ID` and `ADDRESS_TYPE` are `varchars`.  Is there a way to force the query to use `varchar` instead of `nvarchar`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to force the query to
>   use varchar instead of nvarchar?

You will have to modify the source code of SubSonic to change this behavior.

Comment: OK, I have downloaded the source and will start digging around.  Any idea why they would always use nvarchar parameters when the field is a varchar?

Comment: It's probably hard coded in there somewhere.  It's a fairly simple library, they're probably using it for any char field, and it hasn't really undergone the kinds of detailed optimizations one might except from a larger more mature library (like NHibernate or EF, not that they're perfect).

Answer (score 0):

[Previous answer is correct -- further details follow.]

The use of nvarchar is hard-coded in a function called GetNativeType() in Sql2005Schema.cs. it's easy enough to patch and rebuild. Hey, this is OSS! This is what the source code is for!

Here is the code.

```
            case DbType.AnsiString:
            case DbType.AnsiStringFixedLength:
            case DbType.String:
            case DbType.StringFixedLength:
                return "nvarchar";
```

In theory, the generated code (see SQLServer.ttinclude) actually does generate DbType.AnsiString and DbType.String as separate types. It should be possible to split the switch statement and generate "varchar" for one and "nvarchar" for the other. Maybe the author thought it wouldn't matter. I suggest you give it a try (but it may break the unit tests).